# Meu banco de dados tem "sim", "não" e "-". Gostaria de substituir todo o banco de dados por "1" e "0" em uma operação do dplyr

Tags: r

Vi que há formas de substituir coluna a coluna usando as funções mutate() e coalesce(), mas como substituir todos os valores de um banco de dados de uma vez?

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma simples.

```
library(dplyr)
```

### Criando dataframe de teste

```
df <- as.data.frame(list(col_sn = c("sim", "nao", "sim", "-")))
df
  col
1 sim
2 nao
3 sim
4   -
```

### Mudando valores

```
df <- df %>% mutate(col_sn = case_when(col_sn == "sim" ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))
```

### Resultado

```
df
  col_sn
1      1
2      0
3      1
4      0
```

**Nota**: Caso existam outros valores na coluna `col_sn` diferentes de `sim`, `nao`, ou `-` eles também serão substituídos pelo valor `0`

**Atualizado em 14-03-23**

Caso você possua várias colunas, você pode iterar conforme abaixo:

```
df <- as.data.frame(list(col_sn = c("sim", "nao", "sim", "-"), outra_sn = c("sim", "nao", "-", "-")))
 
df
  col_sn outra_sn
1    sim      sim
2    nao      nao
3    sim        -
4      -        -

for (col_name in names(df)) {
    df <- df %>% mutate(!!sym(col_name) := case_when(!!sym(col_name) == "sim" ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))
}

df
  col_sn outra_sn
1      1        1
2      0        0
3      1        0
4      0        0
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta. Há alguma forma de substituir todo o banco de dados? Há muitas colunas para nomear uma a uma na função mutate.

Comment: Resposta atualizada.

Comment: nossa, muito obrigado. vou demorar um tempo até entender sua resposta pois ainda estou acabando de começar no R.

Comment: Para quem votou negativo, poderia dizer o motivo para que eu melhore a resposta?

Comment: 3 votos positivos e 3 votos negativos. Se têm comentários para melhorar a resposta, comentem. Se sabem responder melhor, respondam. Se a resposta está ruim, vote negativo e diga o porquê.